# ¿Es necesario u obligatorio que una función siempre tenga un parámetro?

Tags: python

Buscando información sobre funciones en python, encontré que en la mayoría de casos una función lleva parámetros, y me preguntaba si en el caso de este código que hice, es necesario poner uno, ya que hay entradas por teclado y creo que el parámetro prácticamente "no tiene relevancia".
Posdata: Soy nuevo en esto de la programación :)

```
#imprimir números impares en una lista, según el rango que indique el usuario

def impares():
    a = int(input('Ingrese el numero minimo: '))
    b = int(input('Ingrese el numero maximo: '))

    list = []

    if a > b:
        print('Ha ocurrido un error, vuelva a intentarlo')

    elif a == b:
        print('No hay numeros enteros intermedios')

    else:
        for i in range(a+1, b): 

            if i % 2 != 0:
                list.append(i)

        print("\n" + f"- Los numeros impares entre {a} y {b} son {list}" + "\n" + "\n" + f'- Cantidad de numeros impares entre {a} y {b}: {len(list)}')

impares()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Las ventajas de las funciones es poder reutilizar el código.

En tu caso no es necesario agregar parámetros dado que no los necesita, pero ese código no se ve muy reutilizable.

Supongamos que ahora en vez de que los números se ingresen por el teclado, quieres que se haga con dos números aleatorios.

en ese caso tendrías que hacer esto

```
import random
def impares():
    a = random.randint(1,10)
    b = random.randint(1,10)

    list = []

    if a > b:
        print('Ha ocurrido un error, vuelva a intentarlo')

    elif a == b:
        print('No hay numeros enteros intermedios')

    else:
        for i in range(a+1, b): 

            if i % 2 != 0:
                list.append(i)

        print("\n" + f"- Los numeros impares entre {a} y {b} son {list}" + "\n" + "\n" + f'- Cantidad de numeros impares entre {a} y {b}: {len(list)}')

impares()
```

Y ya te quedaría.

Pero ahora supongamos que quieres hacerlo tanto con números aleatorios, como números ingresados por el teclado, tendrías que hacer algo así

```
    def impares():
        a = int(input('Ingrese el numero minimo: '))
        b = int(input('Ingrese el numero maximo: '))

        list = []

        if a > b:
            print('Ha ocurrido un error, vuelva a intentarlo')

        elif a == b:
            print('No hay numeros enteros intermedios')

        else:
            for i in range(a+1, b): 

                if i % 2 != 0:
                    list.append(i)

            print("\n" + f"- Los numeros impares entre {a} y {b} son {list}" + "\n" + "\n" + f'- Cantidad de numeros impares entre {a} y {b}: {len(list)}')

impares()

def impares_random():
    a = random.randint(1,10)
    b = random.randint(1,10)

    list = []

    if a > b:
        print('Ha ocurrido un error, vuelva a intentarlo')

    elif a == b:
        print('No hay numeros enteros intermedios')

    else:
        for i in range(a+1, b): 

            if i % 2 != 0:
                list.append(i)

        print("\n" + f"- Los numeros impares entre {a} y {b} son {list}" + "\n" + "\n" + f'- Cantidad de numeros impares entre {a} y {b}: {len(list)}')

impares_random()
```

la cantidad de código es exagerada teniendo en cuenta que ambas funciones hacen lo mismo salvo que uno con número aleatorios y otro con números del teclado.

Tu función bien podría quedar bien simplificada así

```
import random

def impares(a, b):

    list = []

    if a > b:
        print('Ha ocurrido un error, vuelva a intentarlo')

    elif a == b:
        print('No hay numeros enteros intermedios')

    else:
        for i in range(a+1, b): 

            if i % 2 != 0:
                list.append(i)

        print("\n" + f"- Los numeros impares entre {a} y {b} son {list}" + "\n" + "\n" + f'- Cantidad de numeros impares entre {a} y {b}: {len(list)}')

impares(random.randint(1,10), random.randint(1,10))
impares(int(input('Ingrese el numero minimo: ')), int(input('Ingrese el numero maximo: ')))
```

Puedes notar la diferencia?

Con una simple función bien estructurada podrías hacer ambas formas si así lo quisieras, esta son las ventajas de las funciones.